# order of $\langle (123) , (234) \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

As homework the teacher asks us to determine how many elements are there in  $\langle (123) , (234) \rangle \subset S_4$ .

I've started doing all the multiplications between the elements, and I've counted so far $9$ different elements. But I think there is a easier way to determine the order of this subgroup of $S_4$. My argument is:

$(123)$, $(234)$ are even permutations, so they can generate only even permutations. So our subgroup has at most $12$ elements. I've counted so far $9$ distinct elements, so using the Lagrange Theorem it must have 12 elements.

Is it correct this argument?

Comment: Riccardo, please help here [Given 2 elements x,y∈S4, is there any particular trick to determining the subgroup generated by them?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4270427/given-2-elements-x-y-in-s-4-is-there-any-particular-trick-to-determining-the)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct. If you know orbit-stabilizer, then here is a quicker method: These two permutations can move 1 to 2 to 3 to 4, so the subgroup of elements that move 1 to 1 has index 4 and 4 divides the order of the group. Also there is an element of order 3, so Lagrange says that 3 divides the order of the group, and thus 12 divides the order of the group. Since all the permutations are even, it is a subgroup of the alternating group, which has order 12. The only possibility is that it is the alternating group.

Comment: Jack Schmidt, please help here [Given 2 elements $x,y \in S_4$, is there any particular trick to determining the subgroup generated by them?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4270427/given-2-elements-x-y-in-s-4-is-there-any-particular-trick-to-determining-the)